# SQL Modify String for CLOB

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, clob

I have a field in a table that is of the text type, however it has the size of 8000 characters, in the Oracle database it gives the problem, I saw that if I switch to CLOB it works, however I am not getting using the syntax `ALTER TABLE "table" MODIFY LOB ("column")`

I need both the query for oracle and mysql, but I'm not finding a syntax from MODIFY text to CLOB to mysql

Comment: What is the data type in Oracle to begin with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**MySQL** doesn't have a data type CLOB it has **TEXT**

```
Data Type   
(CLOB)      

TINYTEXT        L + 1 bytes, where L < 2**8  (255)
TEXT            L + 2 bytes, where L < 2**16 (64 K)
MEDIUMTEXT      L + 3 bytes, where L < 2**24 (16 MB)
LONGTEXT        L + 4 bytes, where L < 2**32 (4 GB)
```

You didn't find anything because they are called differently and are differently see size

so MySQL

```
ALTER TABLE `mytqable` MODIFY `colmunname` LONGTEXT
```

But **oracle** itself has the data type [CLOB](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.10.1.2/ref/rrefclob.html)

```
alter table mytable modify (blob_column clob);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, If I have a text column and want to convert it to CLOB can I? or do I have to convert to Long first?

Comment: you can convert in mysql without a a problem, as long as the data size fits. the conversion to Clob in oracle, should only be made after a backup. And you should be prepared tp generate a CLOB column and copy the data.

Comment: can't i just convert to long and then to clob? how did I see in an answer?
`ALTER TABLE table MODIFY column long;
ALTER TABLE table MODIFY column clob;`

Comment: As i stated, it is possible, but it can cause problems, so be prepared